# Stochastic gradient descent convergence rate

Tags: optimization, convergence, convex

I need to understand the convergence rate notation in the convex optimization context.

In every paper that I find, the convergence rate of an algorithm is defined as a function of the number of iterations ($1/T$, $1/T^2$, ...). But in every explanation out there, the convergence rate is defined based on the ratio of the distance to the optimal function value in step $k+1$ and step $k$.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how the convergence rate is calculated as a function of the number of iterations or provide any resource that explains the concept.